# Scroll bar is not coming in the right it is falling in the center in listbox

Tags: wpf

```
 <!--listBoxWithAutoScroll_Vertical-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" Color="#FFCCCCCC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" Color="#FFEEEEEE"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="6"/>
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#989590" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Width="6" Background="Gray" 
                            BorderBrush="#989590" BorderThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
         <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="2" Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                          BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}" >
                        <Path HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="Gray"
                            Data="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                            Opacity="{Binding Path=Opacity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxWithAutoScroll_Vertical" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}" >
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value >
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer">
                            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Orientation="Vertical" 
                                                           Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                                           Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                                           ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                                           Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}">
                                            <ScrollBar.Template>

                                                <ControlTemplate>
                                                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                                                        <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                            <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"
                                                                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                                        </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                            <RepeatButton Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"
                                                                        Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"/>
                                                        </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                                        <Track.Thumb>
                                                            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" 
                                                                     Background="Gray" Opacity="0.8"/>
                                                        </Track.Thumb>
                                                    </Track>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </ScrollBar.Template>
                                        </ScrollBar>
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Grid x:Name="Panel">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="LineUpButton" Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                                  Content="M 0 8 L 32 8 L 16 0 Z"      
                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"       
                                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"
                                  ClickMode="Hover" />
                            <RepeatButton x:Name="LineDownButton" Grid.Row="2" Height="20" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButton}"
                                  Content="M 0 0 L 16 8 L 32 0 Z" 
                                  Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"       
                                  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=scrollviewer}"
                                  ClickMode="Hover"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                                <Condition Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" SourceName="scrollviewer" Value="Visible"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="LineUpButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                <Setter TargetName="LineDownButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineUpButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineDownButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineUpButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LineDownButton" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value >
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I have a listbox where i display set of images in stack panel.  The scroll bar which i added is coming on the center of the listbox it is not showing in the right corner of the listbox. Can somebody help

Comment: have you tried setting HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" on your ScrollViewer?

Answer (score 0):

One way to put the scrollbar on the right is to add `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` to the `<ScrollBar>` control.  This will move the scrollbar over to the right, but it will mean that the scrollbar and the scrolled contents will overlap if the `ListBox` is not wide enough to fit them both.

If you want to prevent the scrollbar and the scrolled contents from overlapping, you need to modify the `Grid` that contains the `ScrollBar` and the `ScrollContentPresenter`.  Add two `ColumnDefinition`s to this `Grid` and put these two controls in the two different columns:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1">
        <!-- ScrollBar contents and other properties omitted for brevity -->
    </ScrollBar>
    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

Column 1 (which contains the scrollbar) has a `ColumnDefinition` with a `Width` of `Auto`, so that this column only gets the space it needs.  The `ScrollContentPresenter` goes in column 0, whose `Width` is left as the default, which means it gets all of the remaining space.